# Angular 4 fire click event on element selected through keyboard arrows

Tags: angular, keyboard, click, viewchild

At the moment I am able to go through each message in the list applying css class "message-list-active" by pressing arrow keys up and down. When I click on row I trigger click function and pass message object. But cant seem to fire click on the element when pressing arrow keys, I tried to click it through #fire but it only clicks first element and won' allow me to go to the next list.

app.html

```
<div #fire *ngFor="let message of messages; let i=index" 
           (click)="addMessage(message); activeIndex = i"

  [ngClass]="{'message-list-active': activeIndex === i  }">
     {{message}}
  </div>
```

component.ts

```
 messages;  // we have date stored here
 activeIndex = 0;

  onAddtoMessage(message) {
    message.active = !message.active;

}

  @ViewChild('fire') fileInput: ElementRef;

  @HostListener("document:keydown", ['$event']) 
  doSomething(event: KeyboardEvent): void {


    if (event.code == "ArrowUp" && this.activeIndex > 0) {
        this.activeIndex--
        this.fileInput.nativeElement.click()
    }
    if (event.code == "ArrowDown" && this.activeIndex < this.messages.length - 1) {
        this.activeIndex++
        this.fileInput.nativeElement.click()
    }
   }
```

How to fire click function on selected row(object) using arrow key up/key down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so figured it out by binding to id, so you get element by id and apply a click, first set an id

```
<div id="{{i}}" *ngFor="let message of messages; let i=index" 
       (click)="addMessage(message); activeIndex = i"
      [ngClass]="{'message-list-active': activeIndex === i  }">
      {{message}}
 </div>
```

component.ts

```
if (event.code == "ArrowUp" && this.activeIndex > 0) {
    this.activeIndex--
     document.getElementById(this.activeIndex.toString()).click();
}
if (event.code == "ArrowDown" && this.activeIndex < this.messages.length - 1) {
    this.activeIndex++
     document.getElementById(this.activeIndex.toString()).click();
  }
}
```